# Cambiar texto de botón con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando cambiar el texto de botón con JavaScript, ¿por qué no funciona?

```js
function FbotonOn() {
  var uno = document.getElementById('botonOn');
  if (uno.value == 'off') uno.value = 'on';
  else uno.value = 'off'; }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="botonOn" onclick="FbotonOn(this)" >on</button>
```

Comment: Hola Vicente, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Buena primera pregunta. Si quieres ver más sobre el sitio y ver cómo funciona en general, te recomiendo que completes el [tour]. Saludos.

Comment: @Einer, la otra pregunta es usando un `<input type="button"`, considero que no es duplicada, porque las respuestas no solucionan el problema para el caso de un `<button>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar una función ternaria para que el código sea menos saludos espero te ayude

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<button type="button" id="botonOn" onclick="FbotonOn()"> on </button>

</body>
</html>

<script>
var valor = true
function FbotonOn() {
  var uno = document.getElementById('botonOn');
  valor?uno.innerText = "off":uno.innerText = "on";
  valor=!valor
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Tu quieres cambiar el elemento que esta dentro de las etiquetas, ese campo se accede vía `innerHTML`, en tu caso debes usar lo siguiente:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<button type="button" id="botonOn" onclick="FbotonOn()"> on </button>

</body>
</html>

<script>

function FbotonOn() {
  var uno = document.getElementById('botonOn');
  if (uno.innerHTML == 'off') 
      uno.innerHTML = 'on';
  else uno.innerHTML = 'off'; 
}

</script>
```

Como señala [@Marcos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/16597/marcos) tambien puedes usar innerText:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<button type="button" id="botonOn" onclick="FbotonOn()"> on </button>

</body>
</html>

<script>

function FbotonOn() {
  var uno = document.getElementById('botonOn');
  if (uno.innerText == 'off') 
    uno.innerText = 'on';
  else uno.innerText = 'off'; 
}

</script>
```

Otra opción con la ayuda de [@Alvaro Montoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/250/alvaro-montoro):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<button type="button" id="botonOn" onclick="FbotonOn()"> on </button>

</body>
</html>

<script>

function FbotonOn() {
 var uno = document.getElementById('botonOn');
  if (uno.textContent == 'off') 
    uno.textContent = 'on';
  else uno.textContent = 'off'; 
}

</script>
```

Comment: Otra opción es usar `innerText`, si es que no se quiere agregar código `HTML`

Comment: también valdría [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)